# Examples of Recursion uses

Tags: recursion

#### What would be an example of using recursion (with little explanation and/or code sample)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uses: Parsing; traversal; generating fractals; some forms of encryption

Examples: Towers of Hanoi; Fibonacci Seq; Subset generation (there are tons of examples, I can code a few of these for you if you want?)

Advantages: Simple; Intuitive for certain problems (e.g. Ackermann function, traversal)

Disadvantages: Slow (although you can implement any recursive solution using stacks); May result in stackoverflow exception

In case, anyone is wondering about encryption, here is a short explanation of Cipher Block Chaining Mode:

> Chaining adds a feedback mechanism to the block cipher. Blocks are
>   first encrypted, and their results are then fed back into the
>   encryption of the next block. Each block thus modifies the encryption
>   of the next block.
>
> In CBC, the plaintext is first encrypted, with the result stored in a
>   feedback register. Then the next plaintext is XORed with the contents
>   of the register. This becomes the next input of the encryption
>   routine. The resulting encryption is stored in the feedback register
>   again and the next plaintext is XORed with this. This process repeats
>   till the end of the message. For decryption, a block is decrypted
>   normally and stored in the feedback register- after the next block is
>   decrypted, it is XORed with the results of the feedback register and
>   so on.

[adapted from Bruce Shneier's excellent book, [Applied Cryptography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471117099)]

Comment: @Oddthinking there are numerous algorithms which make use of the previous encrypted block (or some previous value) as an input to encrypt the next block e.g. cipher block chaining mode, cipher feedback mode or even simple XOR operations.

Comment: Thanks, Dhruv. I don't doubt that such algorithms *could* be implemented with recursion, but this isn't a classic recursion example where each step is a smaller, simpler problem than the last. Given the streams could be running continuously, unbounded, you are risking a stack overflow.

Comment: @Oddthinking you're right, this isn't a classic recursion example. but it is an intuitive example. the base case can start with the initialisation vector and can recurse from there. but yes, there is definitely a risk of stack overflow with continuous streams. so i've changed my answer to reflect some form of uncertainty.

Answer (score 1):

Any kind of loop can be expressed as tail recursion, and it's commonly used in functional languages. Building/processing any kind of recursive data structure, obviously — tree is one thing, but e.g. lists can be expressed recursively, too (as head being the element and tail being the rest [another list]).

Answer (score 1):

Any problem that can be solved iteratively can be solved recursively. I would question the validity of the question being asked because solving a problem iteratively vs recursively mostly depends on the specific circumstances.

Comment: Generally: performance and stack depth. Specifically: The factorial function. Or tree traversal with very deep trees.